# Getting a TypeRef of a function result type

Tags: haskell, reflection

Following is my failing attempt to extract a `TypeRef` of `b`:

```
import Data.Typeable

f :: Typeable b => a -> b
f = impl
  where
    bTypeRep = typeOf $ (undefined :: Typeable b => (a -> b) -> b) impl
    impl = undefined
```

The error message is following:

```
Could not deduce (Typeable a0) arising from a use of `typeOf'
  from the context (Typeable b)
    bound by the type signature for f :: Typeable b => a -> b
    at src/Xet.hs:14:6-25
  The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

What is wrong? How to solve this?

Comment: Look into `ScopedTypeVariables`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that type variables are not scoped in standard Haskell, so there is no connection between the type variables in the signature of `f` and those in your type annotation. You might as well have written

```
bTypeRep = typeOf $ (undefined :: Typeable d => (c -> d) -> d) impl
```

The solution, as luqui suggested in the comments, is to enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension. Note that this doesn't make all type variables scoped; you have to use explicit `forall` quantifiers to indicate to the compiler when you want type variables to be scoped.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Typeable

f :: forall a b. Typeable b => a -> b
f = impl
  where
    bTypeRep = typeOf $ (undefined :: Typeable b => (a -> b) -> b) impl
    impl = undefined
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why the `forall a b . ` part makes the difference?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov It's part of the extension. "A declaration type signature that has explicit quantification (using forall) brings into scope the explicitly-quantified type variables, in the definition of the named function."

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: Those would have been added implicitly by the compiler anyway. With this extension they simply serve the additional purpose of marking type variable scopes since you probably don't want them to always be scoped.

Answer (score 0):

The following has solved the issue. Thanks to *luqui*.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Typeable

f :: forall a b . Typeable b => a -> b
f = undefined
  where
    bTypeRep = typeOf $ (undefined :: b)
```

I'm willing to accept another answer explaining, why the `forall a b .` part makes the difference, and possibly other solutions.